# Changing a hostname permanently in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I want to create a shell script that can change the hostname of my Ubuntu permanently. Whenever I use the `hostname New_hostname` command, it returns to the original hostname after I restart the machine.

I found out that the only way I can change this permanently is by modifying the file in `/etc/hostname` and save it. Is there some way I can do this using a shell script only? I also have a password.

Comment: `usermod --login new_name old_name`. But don't, it would mess up your homedir and quite some other stuff.

Answer (score 22):

The `hostnamectl` combines setting the hostname via the `hostname` command and editing `/etc/hostname`. Unfortunately, editing `/etc/hosts` still has to be done separately.

```
hostnamectl set-hostname <new-hostname>
```

Answer (score 15):

Type

```
echo "myNewHostName" > /etc/hostname
```

in any shell with root access near you..

You may also want to take a look at the file `/etc/hosts`, cf. http://pricklytech.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/ubuntu-change-hostname-permanently-using-the-command-line/.

Answer (score 12):

## In Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Hostname changing via SSH is reverted after reboot in Ubuntu 18.04. Make permanent change as following way.

#### 1. Edit **/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg**

```
sudo nano /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
```

Set *preserve_hostname* to *true*

> preserve_hostname: true

#### 2. Run hostnamectl

```
hostnamectl set-hostname new-host-name
```

#### 3. Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Change hostname permanently without reboot

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1    persistent_host_name
```

**/etc/hostname**

```
persistent_host_name
```

**Apply changes Immediately**

```
$ sudo hostname persistent_host_name
```

**Check changes**

```
$ hostname
persistent_host_name
```

Answer (score 2):

## Change Hostname on Ubuntu 18.04

### Definition

A hostname is a label that identifies a machine on the network. You shouldn’t use the same hostname on two different machines on a same network.

### Prerequisites

- User should have a sudo privileges

### Change the Hostname

Change the hostname using hostnamectl command. If you want to change the hostname to new_hostname

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname new_hostname
```

It will not change the hostname directly. You want to preserve the changes permanently then you have to edit `cloud.cfg` file

```
sudo nano /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg

# This will cause the set+update hostname module to not operate (if true)
preserve_hostname: true
```

Save the file and close your editor.

### Verify your Changes

You can verify your changes using command `hostnamectl` it will show **new_hostname** under **Static hostname**

PS: Source [Link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-change-hostname-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would need to change it in these files:

```
/etc/hostname
/etc/hosts
```

If you are using some advanced printers, also here:

```
/etc/printcap
```

This is why I would recommend doing it manually - but search the old hostnames first. To find all occurrences in /etc:

```
sudo grep -iRI "_OLDHOSTNAME_" /etc 2>/dev/null
```

Then change the _OLDHOSTNAME_ in every occurrence.
Done.

Answer (score 1):

To chaneg the Hostname permanet in ubuntu machine

Go to :

```
 #vim /etc/hostname
```

Type the **hostname** inside the file you want to set for the machine

Then save and the file

After saving the document run this command

```
 # hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

Then edit the **/etc/hosts** file

```
 #vim /etc/hosts
```

*type the **ip**  **hostname*** inside the file

Then Logout of of the machine and relogin into the machine

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change host name, because its getting displayed as a command prompt in the terminal. Then you can replace `\h` in `PS1` with "desired_host_name" in `~/.bashrc`

Like in `~/.bashrc` put this line at end of file:

```
export PS2="continue-> ";
export PS1="\u@3050:~$ ";
```